# If Akira Kuno can interact with others through his proxy Anno Un, then why didnt he use it to talk with his mother?

Tags: undead-unluck

I'm not sure if I understood this at all. Anno Un is an avatar of Akira Kuno that allows him to interact with others. Then, why didnt he use to talk with his mother, which, not being able to talk and interact with her, was the reason of all the trauma of his life?